# what does it mean by a distribution $u\ge0$?

Tags: distribution-theory

I come across an exercise on distribution theory. It says if $u$ is a distribution on real line $R$, show that:
if $u'\ge0$, then $u$ is an increasing function.
I don't know what does it mean by $u'\ge0$. And obviously $u'$ denotes the distribution derivative of distribution $u$.

Comment: If $T$ is a distribution, then $T \geq 0$ means that $T$ is a positive functional, i.e., for any test function $\varphi \geq 0$ we have $\langle T, \varphi \rangle \geq 0$. If $T = T_f$ is induced by a locally integrable function $f$, then this is equivalent to $f \geq 0$ a.e., justifying the notation.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have got your point. But is there notation like:$u\le0$ or $u\lt0$, or $u\gt N$. If there is, what does it mean

Comment: There is the notation $u\geq v$ meaning that $u-v\geq 0$. In particular $u\leq 0$ means that $-u\geq0$.

Comment: @Ginna, is there a notation like $u>v$?

Comment: I just ask about the conventional notations. There is no meaning to define a notation myself. isn't it? And it is equivalently to ask about is there a order > or < in distribution space?

Comment: Of course you can define notations. It happens all the time. That is how all notation came to be.

Comment: At least I haven't seen a strict inequality notation for distribution, but certainly nothing stops you from introducing if it is meaningful and useful. I personally suspect that its usefulness is largely restricted because this notion of inequality is a global property rather than a local property.

Comment: There is an order, and we already defined it. $u\leq v$ when $v-u$ is a positive functional of the space of test functions. But notice that $<$ between numbers is not the name of the order relation. The order relation between numbers is total. So the negation of $a\leq b$ is ($b\leq a$ and $b\neq a$). So, a shortening notation is used $b<a$. The order $\leq$ for distributions is not total.

Comment: @SangchulLee. Yeah. I haven't seen it either. But it is not so strange to have this relation. Since we have a definition of > or < for functions. And for some integrable function, the distribution is just the function. It seems we may define $u>0$ if $u$ is not equal to $0$ and $u\ge0$. And I still wonder when > is defined in this way. If $u'\gt0$, then is $u$ a strictly increasing function?

Comment: Notice that the inequality $f > 0$ for a measurable function $f$ is usually defined as a.e. pointwise sense, which is certainly much stronger than simply saying that $f \geq 0$ a.e. and $f$ is not a zero function. Rather, this is equivalent to $\langle f, \varphi \rangle > 0$ for any test function $\varphi \geq 0$ with $\varphi \neq 0$. This formulation may be used to define the notion of strict inequality $T > 0$ for your purpose.

Comment: @Ginna, I haven't got your point. Yes $\le$ is a partial order. Because it satisfies three partial order axioms:1) $u\le u$. 2) $u_1\le u_2$ and $u_2\le u_1$ imply $u_1=u_2$, 3) $u_1\le u_2$ and $u_2\le u_3$ imply $u_1\le u_3$. So indeed $\le$ is a partial order. And definitely it is not total order. So my question is that is there a strict partial order in distribution space? Note that the strict partial order satisfies two axioms:1) $u<u$ is not true. and 2) $u_1<u_2, u_2<u_3$ implies $u_1<u_3$.

Comment: Every partial order $\leq$ gives you a strict order $a<b$ defined as "$a\leq b$ and $a\neq b$". The question is, so what? Notations, and definitions in general, are useful when they help you write statements of theorems. For example $<$ is useful for a total order because it helps you re-write the hypothesis of the theorem: *($a\leq b$ and $a\neq b$) is equivalent to $b\leq a$ not  being true.*

Comment: @Ginna, I don't think the strict partial order is not useful. For example, if a function's derivative $u'>0$(> is a strict partial order), it may imply $f$ is a strictly increasing function and if $u'\ge0$ is used, we only get it is an increasing function. Anyway, thanks for your comments. Your insight is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't say it wasn't useful. But careful with that theorem you are trying to state. If $u$ is the Heaviside function then its derivative is the Dirac delta. The Dirac delta is $\geq0$ and not the $0$ distribution. But Heaviside is not strictly increasing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.